# Allow Nuxt.js to use more than 2GB of memory on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, nuxt.js

I currently have a memory leak on my Nuxt app, and I am trying to fix it.

In the meantime, on Heroku I scaled up the dyno from PM to PL to avoid the memory exceeded issues.

Unfortunatly, according to the "Memory Usage" graph on Metrics tab, the memory can never exceed 2,2 GB and my app is still crashing at this limit (PL dynos have 14GB).

I tried to increase to 14436 the `--max_old_space_size` variable but I am not seing any changes.

I am wondering what to do to enjoy the full capacity of the dyno until solving my memory leak issue?